# How to write Flash Action Scripts in Linux machine?

Tags: linux, flash

I want to know how to develop flash applications in Linux?

Is it possible, then which are the Applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options for compiling Flash applications:

1. [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3), available for free from Adobe's site.
2. [Haxe](http://haxe.org/), an Actionscript-like language that can compile to SWF (as well as JavaScript and PHP).
3. [MTASC](http://www.mtasc.org/), a compiler for Actionscript 2

For editors and IDEs, you have some options too:

1. [Flex Builder beta for Linux](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/) -- based on Eclipse
2. Your favorite code editor. Just compile from the command line

The [OSFlash Projects page](http://osflash.org/projects) has a list of more compilers, Eclipse plugins, and editors you can check out.